# ¿Cómo capturar archivo en formulario usando jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, web

Quiero cargar un **archivo** de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-group">
        <label class="input-group-btn">
            <span class="btn btn-primary" id="eFileS">
                Browse&hellip; 
                <input type="file" style="display:none;" id="myFile">
            </span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y quiero tomar el **archivo** con JQuery lo estoy haciendo así:

```
$('#myFile')[0].files[0];
```

Cuando imprimo `$('#myFile')` en un alert me muestra que es un **Object file** pero cuando utilizo `$('#myFile')[0].files[0]` me muestra `{}`

Comment: igualmente sin el display none es decir sin ningun css no logro capturar el valor....quiero enviar el archivo por ajax con form data para poder guardarlo en una ruta

Comment: Esta pregunta podría hallar respuesta aquí: [¿Cómo leer un archivo .txt desde JavaScript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/54745/29967) Si el OP _da señales de vida_ y dicha respuesta resuelve su problema, se podría migrar aquí la respuesta ya que tanto esta como aquella parecen haber sido abandonadas por ambos OP. Sería bueno que alguna de las dos preguntas quede marcada como solucionadas, pero eso depende de quien formuló la pregunta sea aquí o allí.

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener el valor de tu input file podria ser asi :

```
var file = $("#myFile").val();
```

Si quieres obtener el File te recomiendo utilizar `FileReader API` , asi lo trabajas como objeto

```
var file = document.getElementById('myFile').files[0];
if(file){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file);
    reader.onload = function(e){
        alert(e.target.result);
    };
}
```

Obteniendo `var file = document.getElementById('myFile').files[0];` puedes imprimir `file.name`, `file.type`, `file.size`