# ¿Cómo leer un archivo .txt desde JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un archivo `.txt` en la ruta `res/texto.txt`, y desde un javascript quiero leerlo para recorrerlo por líneas y eso.

Necesito saber como puedo leerlo.

Comment: y porque no en PHP es mas facil  `<?php echo file_get_contents('text.txt'); ?>`

Comment: Para abrir un archivo puedes usar la API file de HTML5, pero te aviso que si pretendes abrir un documento del cliente no vas a poder sin que sea este quien lo seleccione, por razones obvias de seguridad.
https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/

Answer (score 26):

Dependiendo del **lado** en que se encuentre el archivo, podrías proceder de dos maneras: leyendo el archivo desde el dispositivo del cliente (explicado en A), o desde el servidor (explicado en B).

#### A. SI EL ARCHIVO ESTÁ DEL LADO DEL CLIENTE

Puedes hacerlo usando [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FileReader). El cliente debe seleccionar el archivo haciendo clic en el botón:

```js
function leerArchivo(e) {
  var archivo = e.target.files[0];
  if (!archivo) {
    return;
  }
  var lector = new FileReader();
  lector.onload = function(e) {
    var contenido = e.target.result;
    mostrarContenido(contenido);
  };
  lector.readAsText(archivo);
}

function mostrarContenido(contenido) {
  var elemento = document.getElementById('contenido-archivo');
  elemento.innerHTML = contenido;
}

document.getElementById('file-input')
  .addEventListener('change', leerArchivo, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file-input" />
<h3>Contenido del archivo:</h3>
<pre id="contenido-archivo"></pre>
```

**Nota:**

Este método es compatible con:

- IE 10+
- Firefox 3.6+
- Chrome 13+
- Safari 6.1+

---

#### B. SI EL ARCHIVO ESTÁ DEL LADO DEL SERVIDOR

Puedes hacerlo con jQuery. En el ejemplo se introduce la url del archivo en el input y al pulsar el botón se pide el archivo al servidor mediante el método get de [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Si la respuesta es satisfactoria, se muestra el archivo en un div.

```html
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
$(function() 
{
$("#button").click( function()
{
   //var TXT_URL = 'https://www.mozilla.org/media/MPL/2.0/index.815ca599c9df.txt';
   var TXT_URL = $("#input-url").val();

    $.ajax
    (
     {
         url : TXT_URL,
   dataType: "text",
   success : function (data) 
   {
             $(".text").html("<pre>"+data+"</pre>");
   }
  }
 );
   });
});

</script>
Ingrese una url válida:<input type="text" id="input-url" size="50" value="https://www.mozilla.org/media/MPL/2.0/index.815ca599c9df.txt"></input>

<input type="button" id="button" value="Ver .txt"></input>
<div class="text">
  <hr />
  <h2>Texto:</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: He estado observado que las respuestas que has dado han sido bastante completas. Parece más bien una documentación. Muy bien explicada. Lo estaba leyendo por curiosidad y me encontré con información útil. Tienes un voto `+1`.

Answer (score 7):

> Tengo un archivo .txt en la ruta res/texto.txt, y desde un javascript quiero leerlo para recorrerlo por líneas.

Si el archivo está en el servidor simplemente utiliza AJAX:

```
fetch('/res/texto.txt')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(content => {
    let lines = content.split(/\n/);
    lines.forEach(line => console.log(line));
  });
```

Si el archivo debe subirlo el cliente, entonces necesitas la File API:

```js
let area = document.getElementById('area');

area.addEventListener('dragover', e => e.preventDefault());
area.addEventListener('drop', readFile);

function readFile (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
  
  if (file.type === 'text/plain') {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = () => printFileContents(reader.result);
    reader.readAsText(file, 'ISO-8859-1');
  } else {
    alert('¡He dicho archivo de texto!');
  }
}

function printFileContents (contents) {
  area.style.lineHeight = '30px';
  area.textContent = '';
  let lines = contents.split(/\n/);

  lines.forEach(line => area.textContent += line + '\n');
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans');

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans';
}

#area {
  align-items: center;
  border: 3px dashed #aaa;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #555;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 80vh;
  justify-content: center;
  max-height: 400px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: pre-line;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 600px;
}

h3 {
  color: #555;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<div id="area">
  <h3>Suelta un archivo de texto y mira qué pasa ;)</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: ERES GENIAL!!!!!!!!!!!!,  Es justo lo que necesitaba. Ahora entiendo como hacer esto. Gracias!!!!!!!