# Cargar archivo JSON y almacenar contenido en variable

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("form.loader").on('submit',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "data.json",
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<form class="loader" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="data">
    <button type="submit">Cargar datos</button>
</form>
```

Entonces, lo que quiero es poder cargar el JSON desde un input file y  *almacenar* todo el contenido del JSON en una variable. Para aplicarle modificaciones y nuevamente volver a guardar el archivo :)

Pero por ahora quisiera solo abrir el archivo para manipularlo.

> En respuesta a @json

Usar load esta genial para mostrar un archivo como tal, pero si quisiera guardar los contenidos en una variable cómo debo hacerlo?

> Y para algunos comentarios...

Bueno, poco uso GET. Por lo general siempre uso POST. Si debo usar GET, me gustaría saber cuál es el motivo :)

---

Comment: No es posible enviar archivos mediante ajax, según tengo entendido. :) donde deseas mostrar el contenido del archivo cargado?

Comment: no está enviando un archivo Está intentando leer text.txt. Para eso, para empezar, debiera ser una petición GET

Comment: GET?, no entiendo. Bueno yo siempre he usado POST.

Comment: @amenadiel pregunta editada.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz un llamado GET es *idempotente*. No cambia su respuesta así lo llames una y otra vez. Un llamado POST está pensado para crear cosas y puede retornar algo distinto cada vez. Dependiendo de tu webserver, un POST hacia un archivo estático puede devolverte cualquier cosa: a veces el contenido del estáticos, otras veces method not accepted. De todos modos no creo que sea ese el problema. ¿Actualmente, alguno de los dos `console.log` está tirando la respuesta a la consola?

Comment: Claro! los console.log estan respondiendo porque data.json es un archivo existente. Esta leyendo **success**, gracias por la informacion respecto a POST y GET

Comment: Pero pues, quisiera poder, segun el input file, leer el archivo en JS y poder guardar sus contenidos en una variable.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz, ¿podrías explicar mejor la parte donde dices "_y almacenar contenido en variable_"? ¿La idea es crear una variable de `JS` donde este el contenido de dicho archivo?, algo como: `var txt = <file-data>`?

Comment: Esta pregunta me sonaba a algo que estuvimos tratando hace poco por aquí. Dejo el enlace de la respuesta, en caso de que pudiera ser útil: http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/54745/29967 Se trataba de mostrar el contenido de un archivo en un input. Hay dos ejemplos de código: **del lado del cliente** y **del lado del servidor**. Teniendo el contenido en un input, almacenarlo en una variable es pan comido. Saludos.

Comment: una pregunta porque no montas un archivo con todo completo osea que en se pueda usar como base de datos un archivo 'txt' en javascript con el crud=insertqar,actualizar,eliminar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dependiendo del **lado** en que se encuentre el archivo, podrías proceder de dos maneras: leyendo el archivo desde el dispositivo del cliente (explicado en A), o desde el servidor (explicado en B).

Tu pregunta:

> Si debo usar GET, me gustaría saber cuál es el motivo :)

la responderé en (C).

**A. SI EL ARCHIVO ESTÁ DEL LADO DEL CLIENTE**

Puedes hacerlo usando [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FileReader). El cliente debe seleccionar el archivo haciendo clic en el botón:

```js
function leerArchivo(e) {
  var archivo = e.target.files[0];
  if (!archivo) {
    return;
  }
  var lector = new FileReader();
  lector.onload = function(e) {
    var contenido = e.target.result;
    mostrarContenido(contenido);
  };
  lector.readAsText(archivo);
}

function mostrarContenido(contenido) {
  var elemento = document.getElementById('contenido-archivo');
  elemento.innerHTML = contenido;
}

document.getElementById('file-input')
  .addEventListener('change', leerArchivo, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file-input" />
<h3>Contenido del archivo:</h3>
<pre id="contenido-archivo"></pre>
```

**Nota:**

Este método es compatible con:

- IE 10+
- Firefox 3.6+
- Chrome 13+
- Safari 6.1+

---

**B. SI EL ARCHIVO ESTÁ DEL LADO DEL SERVIDOR**

Puedes hacerlo con jQuery. En el ejemplo se introduce la url del archivo en el input y al pulsar el botón se pide el archivo al servidor mediante el método get de [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Si la respuesta es satisfactoria, se muestra el archivo en un div.

```html
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
$(function() 
{
$("#button").click( function()
{
   alert('button clicked');
//       var TXT_URL = 'https://www.mozilla.org/media/MPL/2.0/index.815ca599c9df.txt';
   var TXT_URL = $("#input-url").val();

    $.ajax
    (
     {
         url : TXT_URL,
   dataType: "text",
   success : function (data) 
   {
             $(".text").html("<pre>"+data+"</pre>");
   }
  }
 );
   });
});

</script>
Ingrese una url válida:<input type="text" id="input-url" size="50" value="https://www.mozilla.org/media/MPL/2.0/index.815ca599c9df.txt"></input>

<input type="button" id="button" value="Ver .txt"></input>
<div class="text">
  <hr />
  <h2>Texto:</h2>
</div>
```

**C. ¿QUÉ MÉTODO USAR?**

En el primer caso ninguno, ya que el servidor no interviene para nada. En el segundo caso el método GET.

> **The fundamental differences between "GET" and "POST"**
>
> The HTML specifications technically define the difference between "GET" and
>   "POST" so that former means that form data is to be encoded (by a
>   browser) into a URL while the latter means that the form data is to
>   appear within a message body. But the specifications also give the
>   usage recommendation that the "GET" method should be used when the
>   form processing is "idempotent", and in those cases only. As a
>   simplification, we might say that "GET" is basically for just getting
>   (retrieving) data whereas "POST" may involve anything, like storing or
>   updating data, or ordering a product, or sending E-mail.
>
> The HTML 2.0 specification says, in section Form Submission (and the
>   HTML 4.0 specification repeats this with minor stylistic changes):
>
> If the processing of a form is idempotent (i.e. it has no lasting
>   observable effect on the state of the world), then the form method
>   should be GET. Many database searches have no visible side-effects and
>   make ideal applications of query forms.
>
> If the service associated with the processing of a form has side
>   effects (for example, modification of a database or subscription to a
>   service), the method should be POST.

---

> **Las diferencias fundamentales entre "GET" y "POST"**
>
> Las especificaciones HTML definen técnicamente la diferencia entre
>   "GET" y "POST", de modo que GET significa que los datos del formulario
>   deben ser codificados (por un navegador) en una URL mientras que POST
>   significa que los datos del formulario deben aparecer dentro del
>   cuerpo del mensaje. Pero las especificaciones también recomiendan que
>   **el método "GET" debe ser usado cuando el procesamiento de formulario es "idempotent", y sólo en esos casos**. Como una simplificación,
>   podríamos decir que "GET" es usado básicamente para obtener
>   (recuperar) datos mientras que "POST" puede implicar cualquier cosa,
>   como almacenar o actualizar datos, ordenar un producto o enviar correo
>   electrónico.
>
> [La especificación HTML 2.0](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html#SEC8.2) dice, en la sección Formulario de
>   presentación (y la especificación HTML 4.0 lo repite con cambios
>   estilísticos menores):
>
> *Si el procesamiento de un formulario es idempotente (es decir, no tiene un efecto observable duradero...), entonces
>   el método de formulario debe ser GET. Muchas búsquedas de base de
>   datos no tienen efectos secundarios visibles y hacen aplicaciones
>   ideales de formularios de consulta.*
>
> *Si el servicio asociado con el procesamiento de un formulario tiene efectos secundarios (por ejemplo, modificación de una base de datos o
>   suscripción a un servicio), el método debe ser POST.*

Fuente: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html

Comment: +1 Por excelente explicacion, y aclaracion de ciertos puntos inquietantes

Answer (score 5):

bueno si lo que quieres es mostrar el contenido de un txt en un `div` seria mas o menos así.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#texto").load("archivo.txt");
  });
});
```

pones el `div` donde quieres que se muestre y el boton para ejecutar la acción.

```
<button>Cargar Contenido</button>
<div id="texto"></div>
```

espero sea de ayuda.

Comment: Buena respuesta.

Comment: Pregunta editada.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz si quieres guardar el contenido del `txt` en una variable, tras el `load` puedes hacer `var contenido = document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML;`

Comment: Pero si quiero que el usuario pueda seleccionar un json de su computadora, como lo puedo hacer entonces?

Answer (score 2):

Podrías resolverlo usando:

- La [`API FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FileReader) la cual permite leer dinámicamente un archivo ingresado por el usuario.
- El metodo [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse) el cual nos permite tranformar una cadena `JSON` a un objeto.

Ejemplo:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('file'),
  code = document.getElementById('code');

input.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var file = input.files[0];
  
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var json;
    // Aquí mostramos el texto que contiene el archivo
    code.value = e.target.result;

    // Aquí guardamos en una variable el resultado de parsear el JSON
    json = JSON.parse(e.target.result);
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
});
```

```html
<input id="file" type="file" accept="txt/json" /><br/>
<textarea id="code" name="code" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

Una vez que cargues el archivo, puedes guardar el archivo en una SessionStorage o una LocalStoragge, ambos son muy buenos, ya que te deja almacenar datos por el lado del cliente con un maximo de 5mb aprox. La diferencia entre uno y otro, es que Session se elimina si cierras el navegador, el otro no.

Este se invoca de la siguiente manera

```
sessionStorage.setItem('variable', variableJson);
localStorage.setItem('variable', variableJson);
```

Le pasas la "variableJson a la variable de la session o local con el nombre "variable". Esta queda guardada en el pc como archivo temporal. Si necesitas rescatarla, se debe hacer de la siguiente manera.

```
sessionStorage.getItem('variable');
localStorage.getItem('variable');
```

y si necesitas eliminar, basta con

```
sessionStorage.removeItem('variable');
localStorage.removeItem('variable');
```

Espero que te ayude.

Y siempre mejor es post, ya que get, delata los parámetros que le envías a tu servidor por la url. Y se considera como "vulnerable" si necesitase atacar a tu sitio, ya que de esa forma empiezo a entender como funciona tu servidor y como lo puedo botar a través de este bloque.

Exito en lo que estes trabajando :D

Comment: Wow, una respuesta inesperada. Pero muy util, muchas gracias amigo :)

Comment: Si, esto ayuda, mucho a bajar el consumo de datos por red y ademas de consumo de base de datos :D Exito en tu trabajo :D

Answer (score 2):

Partiendo que el archivo esta en el servidor, lo cargaríamos con ***.load()*** de ***jquery*** y almacenáramos el contenido en un ***textarea*** para que lo puedas editar y una vez colocado, los comentarios o cambios que quieras hacerle al archivo, capturas su contenido y lo envias por ***$.post*** a un script de php para guardar los cambios.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //Cargamos el contenido  para el textarea
        $("id_load").click(function(){
            $("#id_textarea").load("demo_test.txt");
        });
        //Enviamos los datos por $.pos para el servidor para guardar los cambios 
        $("id_save").click(function(){
           //Capturamos los cambios hecho al contenido del fichero.
           var text_area = $("#id_textarea").val()
          $.post("script.php",{text_area:text_area},'json');
       });
    });
```

Formulario:

```
 <form class="loader" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <button type="button" id="id_load">Cargar datos</button>
    <textarea name="con_txt" id="id_textarea" rows="40"></textarea>
    <button type="button" id="id_save">Guardar datos</button>
</form>
```

en el script.php para añadir el contenido al final del fichero:

```
<?php 
//Capturamos el datos que viene del formulario con $_POST de php.
$contenido = $_POST['text_area'];
$f = fopen("demo_test.txt", "W");
fwrite($f,$contenido);
fclose($f);
?>
```