# Descargar archivos del sevidor con Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, vb.net, xml

Estoy tratando de descargar archivos del servidor, en este caso (EXCEL, JSON Y XML) estos archivos son generados del lado del servidor con Visual Basic, y al generarlos, del lado del cliente recibe la url donde se encuentra el archivo anteriormente creado, para posteriormente ser descargado.

En el cliente estoy trabajando con JQuery y por lógica con JavaScript, y tengo el siguiente código para realizar la descarga:

```
// http://localhost:7910/.\/Documentos\/ExportarReporte\/EstadisticasProgramacion.xml
var rutaCompleta = servidorWebApi + ruta;

var save = document.createElement('a');
            save.href = rutaCompleta;
            save.target = '_blank';
            save.download = "EstadisticasProgramacion" || 'unknown';

            var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
                'view': window,
                'bubbles': true,
                'cancelable': false
            });
            save.dispatchEvent(evt);

            (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(save.href);
```

pero tengo dos detalles:

1.- Está función no me sirve en Internet Explorer en la versión 11 (Opera y Chrome funcionan perfectamente), y tiene que ver directamente con el `MouseEvent`, y quisiera saber cual es la mejor manera para poder descargar desde Internet Explorer.

2.-En chrome y opera; los archivos xml y excel los descarga sin ningún problema; pero los archivos de tipo json no los encuentra y basicamente los tres tipos de archivos se encuentran en la misma carpeta:

[image: XML, y EXCEL descargado y JSON no lo encuentra]

[image: Archivos en la carpeta]

y ese tipo de archivos se genera através del siguiente código Visual Basic:

```
Private Shared Function CrearJSONProgramacionEncuestas(ByVal encuesta As ENCUESTA, ByVal nombreArchivo As String)
        Using archivo As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("RutaArchivosEncuesta") & "\ExportarReporte\" & nombreArchivo))
            Dim jsonSerialize As New JsonSerializer()

            jsonSerialize.Serialize(archivo, encuesta)
        End Using

        Dim urlDocumento As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("RutaArchivosEncuesta").Replace("~"c, "."c).Replace("/", "\/") & "\/ExportarReporte" & "\/" & nombreArchivo
        Return urlDocumento
    End Function
```

si alguien me pudiera ayudar en esos dos detalles... por favor.

**Error en la búsqueda al servidor desde el navegador:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa si [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/54745/29967) te sirve.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta... pero lo que sucede básicamente es que no puedo descargar los archivos de extensión .json del servidor, cualquier otro tipo de archivo lo descargo sin problema (.xml, .xlsx, .txt), con la función javascript que está en este post... pero es en específico los .json me marca un 404 notfound

Comment: Si la ruta del json es correcta y te da un error 404 suena a alguna restricción para acceder a los archivos con extensión .json en el .htacces o en otra parte.