# Como leer un archivo de texto desde javascript

Tags: javascript

Hola chicos quisiera saber como puedo leer un archivo de texto desde javascript

Comment: Yo quisiera saber que has intentado. Lee las reglas de SO para preguntar en el siguiente enlace: [ask]

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [este articulo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications)

Comment: y en vez de pregunta porque no consulta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/54734/c%C3%B3mo-leer-un-archivo-txt-desde-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Debemos verificar el estatus con 4 (cero)

```
function leeArchivo(file)
{
    var archivo = new XMLHttpRequest();
    archivo.open("GET", file, false);
    archivo.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(archivo.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(archivo.status === 200 || archivo.status == 0)
            {
                var Texto = archivo.responseText;
                alert(Texto);
            }
        }
    }
    archivo.send(null);
}
```

// Llamamos la funcion pasándole como parámetro la ruta del archivo a cargar http://web/archivo.txt:

```
leeArchivo("http://web/archivo.txt");
```

Comment: En caso que no solo fuese ese archivo sino varios no causaria problemas cierto? obviamente se tendria que hacer un recorrido a todos los arhivos para ir leyendo uno por uno

Comment: Si, puedes llamar la funcion con cada ruta de archivo, es la ventaja de que sea una función. Saludos.