# ¿Cómo leer un archivo de texto del lado del cliente? Javascript

Tags: jquery

Quiero leer un archivo de texto alojado en una carpeta en el cliente desde mi sitio web.

Por lo que he investigado en páginas y respuestas de esta misma página sólo se puede hacer solicitándole al cliente que suba el archivo. He intentado subirlo como indican en estas mismas páginas pero me solicita una dirección web.

```
 var archivo = new XMLHttpRequest();
            archivo.open("GET", file, false);
            archivo.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (archivo.readyState === 4) {
                    if (archivo.status === 200 || archivo.status == 0) {
                        var Texto = archivo.responseText;
                        alert(Texto);
                    }
                }
            }
            archivo.send(null);
```

Cuando intento procedimientos como este me marca este error:

```
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

Y en otros procedimientos me dice que no tengo permisos para abrir el archivo (aún cuando ejecuto el navegador como Administrador).

¿Hay algún método que me permita leer el archivo del cliente sin solicitarselo?
Gracias

Comment: Hola, ya habia visto esta pregunta antes, puedes revisar [¿Cómo leer un archivo .txt desde JavaScript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/54734/c%c3%b3mo-leer-un-archivo-txt-desde-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta, Js si puede leer archivos del lado del cliente, siempre y cuando estos los envíe el. No creo que exista alguna manera de leerlos automáticamente. para el ejemplo utilice un archivo txt. Esta respuesta es tomada de [stackoverflow en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/how-to-read-a-local-text-file)

```js
var input = document.getElementById("myFile");
var output = document.getElementById("output");


input.addEventListener("change", function () {
  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    var myFile = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    
    reader.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
      output.textContent = e.target.result;
    });
    
    reader.readAsBinaryString(myFile);
  }   
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="myFile">
<hr>
<textarea style="width:500px;height: 400px" id="output"></textarea>
```

Comment: Sii es que eso si lo he visto, pero no puedo pedirle al cliente que ande cargando el archivo a cada rato :/ por eso deseo hacerlo automático o encontrar alguna otra forma de que una aplicación de escritorio le envíe información a mi sitio web

Comment: Dentro de la misma respuesta puse el link a las respuestas que hicieron del sitio de stackoverflow en ingles, ahí vienen algunos ejemplos. El dilema que veo es que el archivo debe estar en una carpeta que tu le definas al cliente. Creo que lo mas viable es que se lo pidas las veces que lo tengas que hacer si lo que quieres es utilizar solo JS y no otro lenguaje u otra metodología.

Comment: De hecho le defino una carpeta a mi cliente, creo que por eso no habría problema, pero el detalle es que mi sitio web lea esa respuesta que mi aplicación de escritorio escribiría en el archivo. Gracias por el aporte

Comment: Intenté lo del link de stackoverflow en inglés pero es ahí donde me aparece el error: "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https." y cuando lo ejecuto desde Firefox u otro navegador me marca error

Comment: Es eso lo que te dice. "La única manera soportada por el navegador, es mediante peticiones http, 'data', o https" es como una violación a la obtención de datos del sitio al cliente. Imagínate que cualquier página pueda acceder a tu carpeta de **Documentos** así como si nada. De ahí viene esa violación de peticiones. Por eso como te comentaba en mi respuesta, No creo que exista una manera automática de hacerlo.

Comment: Y hay una forma de comunicar una aplicación de escritorio del cliente con un sitio web? Logré ejecutar la aplicación de escritorio enviándole parámetros  desde el sitio web pero no sé como hacer que le responda, he intentado por archivos, leer memoria pero nada :/

Comment: P.D La aplicación de escritorio es propia

Comment: Si, si existe, lee un poco de los Webservices y eso te despejará las dudas

Comment: Los he consumido, pero cómo puedo hacer que interactúen entre dos modos diferentes? (Web y escritorio)

Comment: Formula una nueva pregunta en stackoverflow con esta duda que tienes nueva. Porque esto ya es un caso diferente y así mas usuarios te puedan dar su punto de vista y ayudarte

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aportación

Answer (score -2):

que archivo estas intentando leer? es uno con una ruta asi: C:/carpeta/archivo.text?

Si este es tu caso:

Java script no permite la lectura de archivos fuera del contexto del navegador (Sin solicitarlo mediante un input="file"), esto quiere decir que solo podras leer o modificar archivos que se obtengan o por un **input type="file"** o a mediante una solicitud a un servidor, osea con los protocolos conocidos http, ftp, https, etc.

espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Sii, es un archivo en el disco duro del cliente. Lo que pasa es que tengo un sitio web, y tengo una aplicación de escritorio, la aplicación web lanza la aplicación de escritorio y le debe enviar información al sitio web, pero no sé cómo realizar la comunicación. Estuve intentando con archivos pero parece que no puedo leer lo que manda la aplicación de escritorio en el sitio web entonces.

Comment: No creo, Js si puede leer archivos, siempre y cuando estos los envíe el cliente.

Comment: entonces utiliza un input type="file" para que tu cliente pueda cargar el archivo a tu pagina.