# Especificando una ruta para cargar un .txt con javascript

Tags: javascript, archivo, fileupload

Quiero meter el texto de un .txt en una variable. He encontrado el siguiente código:

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', '/foo.txt');
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
  alert(client.responseText);
}
client.send();
```

Ahora lo modifico quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
var chaintext = client.open('GET', '/foo.txt');
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
  alert(client.responseText);
}
client.send();
console.log(chaintext);
```

Creo un .txt con una frase en la carpeta `C:\Users\USER\Downloads`
Pero nada...
La consola me dice "undefined".
Supongo que hay varias cosas que pueden estar fallando: para empezar que la ruta esté puesta mal o el directorio al que está apuntando el navegador es otro.
¿Alguién sabe como puedo escribir un código que me abra un .txt de una ruta especifica?

Comment: Echale un vistazo a esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/54734/c%c3%b3mo-leer-un-archivo-txt-desde-javascript

Comment: Kiko_L: Ok, Gracias, si la había visto, la había pensado un poco...a ver si alguien me puede dar una respuesta en función del código que he puesto.

Comment: Hola, ¿ y si quizás le indicas la ruta explicita del archivo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El objeto XMLHttpRequest reacciona ante varios eventos. Tu código *escucha* el evento `readystatechange`, que significa que [la variable `readyState` ha variado](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState).

Que el estado cambie no significa siempre que se haya cargado el fichero, porque todos los errores (HTTP status 4XX/5XX) también provocan un cambio del readyState.

Por tanto, para saber qué está pasando podrías hacer algo como:

```
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
  console.log('Respuesta recibida');
  console.log('HTTP status',client.status);
  if (client.status === 200) { // OK
    console.log('Respuesta:',client.responseText);
  } else {
    console.log('Error:',client.statusText);
}
```

Otra opción (a menos que tengas que dar soporte a navegadores muy antiguos) es usar [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch):

```
// fetch no considera una respuesta distinta a 200 un "error",
// esta función lanza el error si la eespuesta no es HTTP 200 OK
function handleErrors(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    return response;
}

let responseProm = fetch('/foo.txt'); // Devuelve una Promise
responseProm
  .then(handleErrors)
  .then(resp => resp.text()).
  .then(text => console.log('El texto es:', text))
  .catch(err => console.log('Error:',err);
```