# Leer variables de archivo de texto

Tags: javascript, html, variables

Lo primero pedir perdón por si no se entiende lo que pregunto o no lo hago de la forma correcta. Soy programador "aficionado" en Delphi, y he hecho pequeñas aplicaciones de gestión para mi empresa.
Ahora el reto es distinto. Necesito leer datos numéricos de un archivo de texto "datos.txt" por ejemplo) almacenado en el propio servidor. 
Algo del tipo;

```
230

123

1,25

190
```

Es decir, serían 8 ó 10 valores en lineas independientes. Necesito leer cada línea y asignar una variable a cada valor, por ejemplo:

```
Variable1 = 230
Variable2 = 123
Variable3 = 1,25
Variable4 = 190
```

Luego esas variables las mostraría en la propia página web, de forma que se vería algo similar a esto

```
Valor de variable 1: 230

Valor de variable 2: 123

...
```

Ya me encargaría de darle formato y que tuviera algo de apariencia.
El caso es que soy absolutamente novato en html y javascript, por lo que ando buscando información para poder realizar este pequeño trabajo que seguro que para muchos de vosotros será bastante sencillo, pero para mí resulta complicado.
Espero haber sido claro en la exposición de lo que busco. Seguiré realizando búsquedas en esta web y otras a ver si soy capaz de solucionarlo y poderme contestar por mi mismo, pero agradeceré enormemente cualquier ayuda para avanzar.

EDITO Y AÑADO:
Por ejemplo en esta pregunta ya respondida encuentro algo de ayuda:
[Pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/54734/c%C3%B3mo-leer-un-archivo-txt-desde-javascript)

Y el código que aparece:

```html
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
$(function() 
{
$("#button").click( function()
{
   //var TXT_URL = 'https://www.mozilla.org/media/MPL/2.0/index.815ca599c9df.txt';
   var TXT_URL = $("#input-url").val();

    $.ajax
    (
     {
         url : TXT_URL,
   dataType: "text",
   success : function (data) 
   {
             $(".text").html("<pre>"+data+"</pre>");
   }
  }
 );
   });
});

</script>
Ingrese una url válida:<input type="text" id="input-url" size="50" value="https://www.mozilla.org/media/MPL/2.0/index.815ca599c9df.txt"></input>

<input type="button" id="button" value="Ver .txt"></input>
<div class="text">
  <hr />
  <h2>Texto:</h2>
</div>
```

En este código, se lee un archivo desde una URL (en mi caso sería siempre el mismo), pero falta asignar los datos a las distintas variables de forma que luego pueda mostrarlos en pantalla en determinadas posiciones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si he entendido bien tu pregunta, en vez de crear una variable por cada linea del archivo veo mas optimo obtener cada linea en una posición de un `array`. Lo puedes obtener con un `split` de salto de linea. Como esto te generara una posición por cada linea del archivo.

Aqui tienes un ejemplo.

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#button").click(function () {
                //var TXT_URL = 'https://www.mozilla.org/media/MPL/2.0/index.815ca599c9df.txt';
                var TXT_URL = $("#input-url").val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: TXT_URL,
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function (data) {
                        let lineasTexto = data.split('\n'); // obtener los datos en un array. Cada posicion es una linea del archivo
                        lineasTexto = lineasTexto.filter(linea => linea.trim() !== ''); // Eliminamos las lineas sin datos
                        for (let index = 0; index < lineasTexto.length; index++) { // Recorremos cada posicion del array para mostrarlo en pantalla
                            $('.text').append(`<p>Valor de variable ${index}: ${lineasTexto[index]}</p>`)
                        }

                    }
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
        Ingrese una url válida:<input type="text"
       id="input-url"
       size="50"
       value="https://www.mozilla.org/media/MPL/2.0/index.815ca599c9df.txt"></input>

<input type="button"
       id="button"
       value="Ver .txt"></input>
    <div class="text">

    </div>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Realmente, como sigo intentado aprender a hacerlo, entiendo que no necesito poner un nombre a cada variable, si no que puedo hacerlo a través de un array. En tu caso lo haces con `lineasTexto[index]`
Por otro lado, en vez de cargar el archivo pulsando un botón, lo que quiero es cargarlo nada más cargar la página, de forma que me muestre los valores sin necesidad de ninguna acción por parte del usuario.

Comment: @NachoIglesias en caso de quieras hacerlo al cargar la pagina sustituye el código `$("#button").click(function () {` por `$(document).ready(function() {` y asegúrate de que `TXT_URL` tenga valor ya asignado.

Comment: Bien, voy aprendiendo poco a poco...
He hecho las modificaciones que me has dicho con lo que obtengo el resultado esperado.

De esta forma, siguiendo tus indicaciones, consigo cargar el archivo y mostrarlo en pantalla al abrir la página.
Pero cuando cambio el archivo anterior del ejemplo https://www.mozilla.org/media/MPL/2.0/index.815ca599c9df.txt
por el que quiero utilizar con mis valores:

    http://soldadurascalderon.com/tmp/datos.txt

no me muestra nada. Sin embargo si esa misma URL la abro en el navegador, sí que me sale la lista de valores en pantalla.
¿Qué es lo que hago mal?

Comment: Verifica que la url este bien y que no te sale ningún error en la consola de desarrollador. (F12 en el navegador pestaña console)

Comment: En la consola del navegador (Chrome) me sale el siguiente error: pg3.html:26 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://soldadurascalderon.com/tmp/datos.txt' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Tienes que habilitar cors. Tu navegador por seguridad esta bloqueando todas las llamadas ya que tu servidor esta proveyendo cabeceras que bloquean ese tipo de llamadas tienes mas información aquí https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS. Para solucionar esto tienes que habilitar el cors en tu servidor. Para ayudarte mejor necesito que me digas en que lenguaje estas usando en tu servidor.

Comment: Algo  habia leido al respecto de CORS, pero sin llegar a entender cómo solucionarlo. El problema es que lo que quiero es que esa página la pueda cargar cualquiera y leer los valores del archivo de texto en pantalla. SI tengo que obligar al cliente a configurar su navegador, creo que no va a poder ser, por lo que necesito un método de leer los valores de ese archivo y poderlos presentar en pantalla de forma sencilla y transparente al usuario. Lo que no entiendo es porqué ciertos archvios txt sí que me los muestre en pantalla y el que yo tengo en el servidor no...

Comment: Por cierto, el servidor es Apache

Comment: Bien, me autorrespondo porque por fin encontré la solución. Efectivamente, era CORS el problema, pero es que como la página la ejecutaba desde mi PC, leía los valores de un servidor externo, en este caso el dominio en que tengo alojado el archivo. 
Por tanto, lo que hice fue subir la página html al servidor y abrirla allí mismo, con lo cual no es necesario ningún tipo de modificación CORS, ya que los datos los lee desde el mismo servidor en que está la página. Supongo que algo muy obvio para incluso los menos expertos, pero para mi ha sido reto importante.

Comment: Muchas gracias al compañero @Sanchis por su ayuda, así da gusto.